# wrong permalink generated by wordpress in php program

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I am developing a wordpress application to maintain animal shelter info.
I installed wordpress in a sub-directory with the plugin "PHP Everywhere".

I created 2 wordpress pages.
"our-pets" (the first page) simply includes the path to the main php program.
In the program, an option can be selected that will document.form1.submit() the action "animals-detail" (the second page).

But wordpress generates/displays the wrong permalink:
WRONG: mysite.com/subdirectory/our-pets/animals-detail
RIGHT: mysite.com/subdirectory/animals-detail

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think in your form's `action` attribute, you've set the value as `animals-detail` without a slash before it. Which will get the current path and add the `action`'s value to it.

Comment: You could, 1) add `action='/animals-detail'` or 2) Use WP's permalink function. E.g. if Id of the `animals-detail` page is `59` use this `action="<?php the_permalink(59); ?>"`

Comment: Great! It worked! (I went with option 1). Actually, because this was in a sub directory under root, I use "../animals-detail"

Comment: I have added these instructions as answer. You can mark the answer as correct to close this thread and that others looking for such solution may find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your form's action attribute, you've set the value as animals-detail without a slash before it. Which will get the current path and add the action's value to it.

You could,

1. add `action='/animals-detail'`
2. Use WP's permalink function. E.g. if ID of the `animals-detail` page is `59` use this `action="<?php the_permalink(59); ?>"`